# In range find this and do that

Tags: excel, vba

Have a range of cell with column headings as weeks In the range of cells I want to look for a number, say

1 if it finds a 1 then look at a column in said row for a variable, 2 or 4 whatever Now I want to put a triangle (can be copy and paste a cell) in the cell that has the "1" in it then skip over the number of week variable and add another triangle and keep doing this until the end of the range. Then skip down to the next row and do the same, until the end of the range.
Then change to the next page and do the same thing... through the whole workbook.

I think I have it done, don't know if it's the best way.

I get a error 91 at the end of the second loop, the first time the second loop ends it goes through the error code.
The second time the second loop ends it errors.

I don't understand it runs through once, but not twice.

```
    Sub Add_Triangles2()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim OffNumber As Integer
    Dim SetRange As Range
    Dim OffsetRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet   

    Set SetRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G25") ' Used to stop the second loop in range

    Worksheets(1).Activate
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select  ' Has item to be pasted (a triangle)
    Selection.Copy

For Each ws In Worksheets
  Worksheets(ws.Name).Activate

    With Range("C4:G25")
        Set Rng = .Find(1, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address
            Do

                Rng.Activate
                ActiveSheet.Paste

                    Do

                        OffNumber = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row)
                        Set OffsetRange = SetRange.Offset(0, -OffNumber)
                            If Not ActiveCell.Address < OffsetRange.Address Then
                                Exit Do
                            Else
                                End If

                        ActiveCell.Offset(, OffNumber).Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                    Loop While (ActiveCell.Address <= OffsetRange.Address)

                    On Error GoTo ErrorLine

                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress

        End If

    End With

ErrorLine:
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True

Next ws

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get an Error 91 using the data set I built from your explanation, maybe a screenshot of the layout could help recreate the issue.

However, I would do something like this, it will look at the value of each cell in the range C4:G25, and if it equals 1, it will paste the symbol stored in Cell A1.

```
Sub Add_Triangles2()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim rngSymbol As Range
Dim intFindNum As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set rngSymbol = Range("A1") 'Set range variable to hold address of symbol to be pasted
intFindNum = 1 'Used to hold number to find
Worksheets(1).Activate

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Worksheets(ws.Name).Activate

    For Each Rng In Range("C4:G25")
        If Rng.Value = intFindNum Then
            rngSymbol.Copy Rng
        End If
    Next Rng

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: That works great but, it does not move over a set number is each row and paste the symbol again and again til the end of the row. In other words it needs a second Loop

Comment: And I have no special format, I just opened a new excel sheet pasted in my code. Added anything to cell A1 on the first sheet. Add numbers in row A for offset and put some "1"s in the rows with the offsets. Do this for 3 pages worth, run the code. It will run two pages the stop with a error

Comment: I understand now. I was able to get it to work by changing the line ` Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress` to `Loop Until Rng Is Nothing Or Rng.Address = SetRange`. I am not exactly sure why the error is being thrown when moving from the 2nd (I did see it correctly update the 1st & 2nd sheets) to the third.

Comment: I still get the same error after changing that line   grrrr

Answer (score 0):

I got it....

```
Sub Add_TriWorking()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim rngSymbol As Range
    Dim intFindNum As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim OffNumber As Integer
    Dim SetRange As Range
    Dim OffsetRange As Range


    Set SetRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G25") ' Used to stop the second loop in range
    Set rngSymbol = Range("A1") 'Set range variable to hold address of symbol to be pasted
    intFindNum = 1 'Used to hold number to find
    Worksheets(1).Activate

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Worksheets(ws.Name).Activate

        For Each Rng In Range("C4:G25")
            If Rng.Value = intFindNum Then
                rngSymbol.Copy Rng
                Rng.Activate
                ActiveCell.Copy
                    Do

                            OffNumber = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row)
                            Set OffsetRange = SetRange.Offset(0, -OffNumber)
                                If Not ActiveCell.Address < OffsetRange.Address Then
                                    Exit Do
                                Else
                                    End If

                            ActiveCell.Offset(, OffNumber).Select
                            ActiveSheet.Paste
                        Loop While (ActiveCell.Address <= OffsetRange.Address)

                    On Error GoTo ErrorLine

            End If
        Next Rng

    ErrorLine:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Next ws

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```